# Change user_pass in wp_user as MD5

Tags: android, wordpress

May I know how I change the user_pass in wp-users for wordpress to MD5, because my android application user password i write in php as MD5, now my application cannot use the user data in wordpress to login because the user_pass in wp-users is start from $P$B. I hope someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the [Change Reset WordPress password from MySQL/PHPMyAdmin](http://wpcrux.com/blog/change-wordpress-password-phpmyadmin/).

(n.b: I've only tested the first method)

**Method#1 – The Long way through phpMyAdmin table editing**

This method involves editing and updating the **wp_users** table values to reset our lost WordPress password. The method is little longer but is also easy enough to follow without knowing technical things.

1. Head over to phpMyAdmin
2. Click on your WordPress database.

[image]

3. Navigate to and click the table wp_users.

[image]

4. Edit the row with your WordPress username.

[image]

5. Now, in the user_pass field, change the function to MD5 and enter your new password in the Value section (refer below screenshot).

[image]

6. Click "Go" or similar option at the bottom to update the table values.

[image]

**Method#2 – The Short way through MySQL**

This methods implements the direct SQL query execution to update the **wp_users** table value to reset our hacked WordPress password.

1. Follow the first 3 steps of the above method.
2. Go to SQL or MySQL section in your phpMyAdmin.

[image]

3. Now, enter the below given query:

   ```
    UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass`= MD5('yourpassword') WHERE `user_login`='yourusername';
   ```

   Put your new password in place of yourpassword and replace yourusername with your WordPress username.

[image]

4. Click "Go" or similar option at the bottom to execute the query.

Comment: but after i login into wordpress again, the password become hash again

Comment: wordpress is not saving the password as a plain text. It is a standard security procedure. When you login with your plain text password, it will be hashed first then compared to the hash password in the database.

Comment: so, mean my application php the password I cannot set MD5 and need set same with Wordpress?

Comment: When you creating the password (which is a plain text), wordpress will automatically hashing it and save the result to the database.

Comment: Now, I register account in my application, the password send in wp-users is MD5, because i set MD5 in php code

Comment: Method#2, The Short way through MySQL, works perfect!